# What are the mechanics of using a dart as a melee weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons

Liz the Wizard is toe-to-toe with her foe, Joe.  If Liz stabs Joe with a dart rather than throwing it, does she still get her proficiency bonus and avoid incurring disadvantage?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Using a dart like this makes it an *improvised weapon*, so no proficiency bonus

PHB 146:

> A **melee weapon**  is used to attack a target within 5 feet of you, whereas a **ranged weapon** is used to attack a target at a distance.

In the weapons table on PHB 148, the dart is listed as a ranged weapon, not as a melee weapon with the thrown property. As such, using it as a melee weapon means you are improvising. From "Improvised Weapons" (PHB 147-148):

> If a character **uses a ranged weapon to make a melee attack** ... it also deals 1d4 damage.

### Unless you have a generous DM

However you might be able to apply your proficiency bonus, if your DM rules that a dart is 'similar to an actual [melee] weapon', a dagger maybe?

### But in any case no disadvantage

Using improvised weapons doesn't automatically incur disadvantage according to the PHB.

*(The DMG does suggest sometimes getting disadvantage when using improvised **tools**. This topic is dealt with in some depth in [this rpg.se answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/50865/20972).)*

### Unless you have an evil DM

Though it's always up to the DM to impose disadvantage, so I suppose he or she might do anyway...

*For more information on using a dart as a **ranged** weapon including ideas about what a dart might look like as a weapon see: [What are the mechanics of using a dart as a ranged weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57237/what-are-the-mechanics-of-using-a-dart-as-a-ranged-weapon)*